# androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView cannot be cast to androidx.core.view.ActionProvider

Tags: java, android, kotlin, androidx

Столкнулся с ошибкой в методе onCreateOptionsMenu во время inflate менюшки.

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
        MenuItem searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setQueryHint("Поиск последний новостей ...");
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                if (query.length() > 2) {
                    onLoadingSwipeRefresh(query);
                }
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                return false;
            }
        });

        searchMenuItem.getIcon().setVisible(false, false);

        return true;
    }
```

menu_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        app:actionProviderClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar"
        />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_weather"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Weather"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_weather"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

Как это можно исправить? Заранее спасибо!

```
Process: com.sv.newsapp, PID: 16248
    java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView cannot be cast to androidx.core.view.ActionProvider
        at androidx.appcompat.view.SupportMenuInflater$MenuState.readItem(SupportMenuInflater.java:425)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.SupportMenuInflater.parseMenu(SupportMenuInflater.java:179)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.SupportMenuInflater.inflate(SupportMenuInflater.java:129)
        at com.sv.newsapp.activities.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:150)
```

Comment: Почему в  ```inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);``` указан ```R.menu.menu_main``` есл фаил называется ```menu_item```? Ведь в тако случии должно быть ```R.menu.menu_item``` иля я чего то не понимаю?

Comment: @НикитаЖуков, потому что опечатка, menu_main называется, но вместо ответа на вопрос - вы решили придраться к опечатке?

Comment: я непридераюсь к опечатке я просто подумал что Вы обращались к не существуюму файлу.

Comment: Не стоит грубить людям, желающим вам помочь. Никто не знает, где вы допустили ошибку - только в вопросе или в вопросе и в своей программе. Ошибка довольно исчерпывающе позволяет понять, что вы неправильно назначаете `ActionProvider` в `xml`: `app:actionProviderClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"`. Возможно, это тоже опечатка, и вы хотели написать `actionViewClass`...

Comment: @ВасяВоронцов, здесь скорее резкость, нежели грубость. Если мои слова задели - что ж, выражаю извинения. А за ваш ответ - спасибо

Comment: @НикитаЖуков, приношу извинения, если выглядело грубо, скорее немного резко ответил ) Впредь буду чётче выражать ответ

Comment: Ошибка говорит о том, что невозможно привести виджет SearchView  к ActionProvider. Я бы хотел поинтересоваться, что вы в принципе задумали, каким образом вообще виджет поиска должен выполнять функцию провайдера?